# I want to get values from multiple URL's in Google Spreadsheet. IMPORTDATA doesnt work

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate, regexextract, importdata

I have 9000 lines with URL's in my Google Sheet.
Example: https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid=233860&item_type=10).
Every URL returns JSON like this:

```
{
"success": 1,
"goo_value": "80"
}
```

I want to put `goo_value` in another cell in the same spreadsheet.

`IMPORTDATA` doesn't work: "Too many requests".

Is there a way how to get these text values? Some script or something?

[image: URL]

Answer (score -1):

- try like this:

  ```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(" ", IMPORTDATA(
  "https://steamcommunity.com/auction/ajaxgetgoovalueforitemtype/?appid=233860&item_type=10")), 
  ":""(.*)""")
  ```

[image: 0]